# How to create a signup form with React and Why won't a function be executed when called insight a form after input field?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, authentication

Im new to react and am trying to implement a sign up form with react and nodes for the backend. Unfortunately, nothing works.

1. Somehow my function which should be invoked when user presses submit button, doesn't even run. I tried to put console.logs and nothing happens, unless I put the button (or whatever element) which invokes the function outside of my form and put it BEFORE my inputs. I have no idea why it is like that and don't know where else I would put a submit button of not below the input fields.
2. I included below my code-perhaps there is something else wrong with it too.

Super grateful for any help!!!

```
    class Signup extends React.Component{
        constructor (props){
            super(props)
            this.state={
                email:'',
                password:''
            }
            this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)
            this.send=this.send.bind(this)
        }
        handleClick(elm){
            console.log("omg")
            this.setState({
                [elm.target.name]: elm.target.value
            })
        }

        send(){
          console.log("sending data");
           const logindata={
            email:this.state.email,
            password:this.state.password
           }
           axios.post('/signup', logindata )
            .then(response=>response.data)

        }
        render(){

        return (
              <div>    
                <form>
                   <input type="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} name="email" onChange={this.handleClick}/>
                   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} name="password" onChange={this.handleClick}/>           
                   <input onClick={this.send} type="submit"/>
                </form>
              </div>

            )
         }
    }
```

backend route:

```
router.post('/signup', function(req,res,next){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is just doing a default form submission. On the `send()` method, have it accept the event as an argument, and prevent the default submission.

```
send(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  // the rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a lot! Do you also happen to know what could be wrong with my axis request? I m getting an 404 error

Comment: @javascripting - I'm not sure about that. Assuming other routes are working, everything looks ok, but I'd need to see the rest of your server code to be able to tell.